# Define a string with single quotation marks?

Tags: c++, arduino-ide

This is kind of a short question. All I want to know is, if I can define a string using single quotation marks ('), instead of the regular ones("). I want to use it in a function like this: 
print('Hello world');

I unfortunately do not have an Arduino nearby so I cannot test it myself.

Comment: [single quotes identify a single character, while double quotes create a string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to achieve rather than your likely misguided idea about how to achieve it (i.e. removing quotes)?

Comment: I am making an extensions for a program that requires Arduino code inside the program, but if I write the quotation marks, the debugger reports an error, because there are quotation marks inside quotation marks.

Comment: Then you need to update your extension to properly escape the arduino code so that reserved/special characters in the code are not interpreted by the non-arduino debugger. How to do that depends greatly on the program you are extending, which you have not named.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're trying to do, but perhaps just escaping the `"`s will achieve what you want.  In C, the way to escape something is with a \, so for example `char myString[] ="\"\"";` would give you a string containing two `"`s.

Comment: You are still not being clear about what you are trying to achieve. What program? Language? Platform? You may want to check out these questions on stack overflow: [“#include” a text file in a C program as a char\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980), and [Embed data in a C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.  `'x'` defines a single character or integer (note: `'ab'` is a two-byte single value [integer] made up from the ASCII values of both characters).

To include `"` within a string you have two options:

1. Escape the `"` with `\`, as in: `char foo[] = "He said \"Hello there\".";`
2. Use "raw strings" if the compiler is configured to support it: `char foo[] = R"(He said "Hello there".)";`

Option 1 is the most portable since it doesn't require compiler support for modern C++ standards. However it's the hardest to read, especially when you get lots of escapes in the same string.

You can make it more readable by defining QUOTE:

```
#define QUOTE "\""

char foo[] = "He said " QUOTE "Hello there" QUOTE ".";
```

Answer (score 6):

**No**, you cannot. This rules comes from the basic C++ syntax on which the Arduino platform is built.

Comment: Is there a way to define it without the qoutation marks?

Comment: Only very convoluted ways.

Comment: Actually, C++ raw string literals are easy to use (ref [1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), [2](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/cpp-11-raw-strings-literals-tutorial/)); the only convoluted bit is adding a  `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` switch to IDE compiler options.